# Cache Invalidate not working in Shiro

Tags: java, jsp, shiro

We are using Apache Shiro for managing auth in our app. When using Permission I am using out of the box memory based caching and here is my shiro.ini.

In my JSP I am using `shiro:taglib` to check for hasPerimission and lacksPemrissons tags. If I **update user role in database** (hence so corresponding permissions), and when user logs-out his permissions are updated. **I see unauthorized page as expected. However, the links are still rendered, which should not.** These links are rendered using following syntax. (note: these links are part of common `header.jsp`, and included in all pages)

```
<shiro:hasPermission name="admin:viewPage">
        <a href="/pages/admin.jsp">Admin</a>
</shiro:hasPermission>
```

My class `JNDIAwareJDBCRealm` inherits `JdbcRealm` which inherits `CacheManagerAware`. It seems that `CacheManagerAware.onLogout()` clears cache.

Is it tag library doing some caching?  Am I missing some implementation with caching?

My Shiro.ini file:

```
[main] 
jndiJdbcRealm=com.my.domian.JNDIAwareJDBCRealm
jndiJdbcRealm.jndiDataSourceName=jdbc/mySQLConnection 
jndiJdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = select password FROM users where email_id=?
jndiJdbcRealm.userRolesQuery= select role from user_roles, user where user.email_id =? AND user.id = user_roles.user_id 
jndiJdbcRealm.permissionsQuery= SELECT permission FROM role_permission WHERE role=? jndiJdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled=true

bcryptCredentialsMatcher=com.my.domain.BCryptCredentialsMatcher
jndiJdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $bcryptCredentialsMatcher

securityManager.realms = $jndiJdbcRealm builtInCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $builtInCacheManager

# unauthorized page
perms.unauthorizedUrl = /pages/unauthorized.jsp
```

(Realized that Shiro has very less documentation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working. Logout workflow was wrongly using `session.invalidate()` in our code.  So two things I required are

1. Use correct logout workflow by invoking `SecurityUtils.getSubject().logout()` instead of session.invalidate().
2. On login clear cache as follows:

.

```
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token)
     throws AuthenticationException {
    ...
    SimplePrincipalCollection principals = new SimplePrincipalCollection(username, "jndiJdbcRealm");
    super.doClearCache(principals);

    ...
}
```